# Bower can't fetch packages through proxy, git is working fine

Tags: git, proxy, bower

I tried to use bower to install JQuery and some other libraries. Unfortunately it fails with no obvious reason (at least with no obvious reason to me :-)

I did the following (on the Windows command line):

```
>bower install jquery
bower jquery#*              not-cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower jquery#*                 resolve https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower jquery#*                 ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128
```

The weird thing is, if I start the mentioned git command by hand it works fine:

```
>git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
bfac0c70b1f7271934a4e081583c2b905ca1d326        refs/heads/1.11-stable
e3a802cbf7d66d88e3659ad344bce86b99d029be        refs/heads/1.9-stable
73c1ceaf4280bd0318679c1ad832181f3f449814        refs/heads/1.x-master
...
```

I am sitting behind a proxy which is obviously correct configured in git (I used git before). I added the proxy config to the .bowerrc but I am not sure if it works correctly. Could that be the problem?

I appreciate every help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `.bowerrc` file add the following lines

```
{
    "directory": "client/bower_components",
    "proxy" : "proxy_address",
    "https-proxy" : "proxy_address",
}
```

And run also the following command

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it: I used another proxy which worked. This is weird because the proxy I used before was working fine in all the other applications. Additionally I marked the answer of Altius as approved, because it is basicly what I did to resolve it.

Thanks!

Edit: Additionally you need to specify HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY as environment variables in Windows! Check if it is correct in the command line with `set`.

Comment: You need to open a command line in windows (run -> cmd). Then you type `set`. You will get a long list of environment variables. Check for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. Be sure to check that the https-proxy uses http instead of https. Or in short: the http-proxy and the https-proxy have the same address!